# Canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to make a "Hidden greeting" using javascript canvas.
it is supposed work in this way,when a user clicks on a region of canvas that regions opacity is decreased.
For changing this opacity I use pixel data(getImageData).
Then I write that text again on that canvas,since the pixel data also changes the text if it was in that region.

The problem I am facing that when I click sometimes in the canvas the text gets visible itself,even if i haven't clicked in the text region.

the code and output can be found here.

See the Pen [JBdJzZ](https://codepen.io/situ25/pen/JBdJzZ/) by situ25 ([@situ25](https://codepen.io/situ25)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

The function fillpos() is called when a click happens on the canvas.

```
function fillpos(ev){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas1");
    if(canvas.getContext)
    {

        var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.fillStyle='rgb(0,240,0)';
        ctx.globalAlpha=0.2;
        var pos=getMousePos(canvas,ev);
        var borderWidth=parseInt(getComputedStyle(document.getElementById("canvas1")).borderWidth);

        var imagedata=ctx.getImageData(pos.x,pos.y,40,40);

        for(var i=0;i<imagedata.data.length;i+=4)
        {
            imagedata.data[i+3]=100;
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imagedata,pos.x,pos.y);
        writeText();

    }
}

function writeText(){
    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas1");
    if(canvas.getContext){

        var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

        ctx.font="40px Georgia";

        ctx.fillText("Hi There",100,100);                       //Write text again
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly related, but what is the point of checking existence of `canvas.getContext`? I'm just wondering if there's a canvas implementation without the said method ...

Comment: @Teemu all browsers released before ~2011

Comment: @Kaiido OK ... but was there even canvas element before that ..? Canvas introduced in FF 3.6 (r 2010), Chrome 4 (r 2010), Safari 3.1 (r 2008!). I've started to play with canvases at some point in 2012, so this is a bit confusing ...

Comment: @Teemu No and that's why at the beginning we had to use such checks, because browsers that didn't support the Canvas API still allowed the element in the DOM, but as an UnknownHTMLElement, and thus this code would have thrown there. Nowadays, we rely on so much other features that we don't really need such checks anymore, it will probably break way before, with any library...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are rewriting the text, uncomment the `fillstyle` and set it to `rgb(0, 255, 0)` to reset the text fill color.

Comment: Thanks @NaN it worked,can you also clarify why that difference of two statements effected the execution.

Comment: Way less complicated than my solution. I would go with this solution if your background is going to be the same color as the text.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem I am facing that when I click sometimes in the canvas the text gets visible itself,even if i haven't clicked in the text region.

Well that is because you are drawing the text on the canvas regardless of which part of it should be revealed and doing so after having drawing the background/foreground, meaning it is drawn last on top of everything else.

With a single canvas you only have a single layer of image data so you cannot 'reveal' something in a canvas that was not there to begin with.

One way to achieve your goal is to have a separate canvas which only contains the image data for the foreground layer (here called `revealLayerCanvas`):

```
var revealLayerCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
revealLayerCanvas.width = canvas.width;
revealLayerCanvas.height = canvas.height;
revealLayerCtx = revealLayerCanvas.getContext('2d');
```

When drawing the canvas first draw the background, then text, then the foreground layer.

```
function redraw(){
   ctx.fillStyle='rgb(0,240,0)';
   ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
   ctx.fillStyle='rgb(0,0,0)';
   ctx.font="40px Georgia";
   ctx.fillText("SECRET",100,100);
   ctx.drawImage(revealLayerCanvas,0,0);
}
```

When dragging over the image you are revealing a piece of the foreground as you have done in your example.

See Pen for the full working example: [Canvas Reveal Layer](https://codepen.io/christiaan-lombard/pen/MBwQzg)